# Trying to delete a uploaded file from directory file system

Tags: grails

I have a web app that uploads files to file system and show them in a list. I am trying to delete the item with a button. I know I need to get the path of the directory file to be able to delete it and I believe this is where I am stuck:

```
def delete = {

    def doc = Document.get(params.id)
    def path = Document.get(path.id)

    doc.delete(path)

    redirect( action:'list' )
}
```

error I am getting: `No such property: path for class: file_down.DocumentController Possible solutions: flash`

It seems to me `def path = Document.get(path.id)` is wrong, in that case how do we find the path of a document ?

This is my upload method where I upload the files, assign it to a specific filesize, date, and fullPath( which is the uploaded folder)

```
def upload() {
    def file = request.getFile('file')
    if(file.empty) {
        flash.message = "File cannot be empty"
    } else {
        def documentInstance = new Document()
        documentInstance.filename = file.originalFilename
        documentInstance.fullPath = grailsApplication.config.uploadFolder + documentInstance.filename
        documentInstance.fileSize = file.getSize() / (1024 * 1024)
        documentInstance.company = Company.findByName(params.company)
        if (documentInstance.company == null) {
            flash.message = "Company doesn't exist"
            redirect (action: 'admin')
        }
        else {
            file.transferTo(new File(documentInstance.fullPath))
            documentInstance.save()
            redirect (action:'list', params: ['company': params.company])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `doc.fullPath`? who wrote the upload method?

Comment: I did @cfrick. And I tried doc.fullPath, it does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have an error in this line:

```
  def path = Document.get(path.id)
```

You try to get path.id from the path variable you are just declaring.

I'm pretty sure that you mean

```
 def path = new File(doc.fullPath)

 path.delete() // Remove the file from the file-system

 doc.delete() // Remote the domain instance in DB
```

Alternative:

```
 class Document {
      // Add this to your Document domain
      def beforeDelete = {
            new File(fullPath).delete()
      }
 }
```

and then you could just do this in your controller:

```
def delete = {

    def doc = Document.get(params.id)

    doc.delete() // Delete the domain instance in DB

    redirect( action:'list' )
}
```

Comment: unless your Document instance has a delete method?